# Getting error in sending email by using gmail SMTP server in windows app

Tags: c#

I am trying to code software in C# to send email via using gmail account with help of the gmail SMTP server. It does not produce any compile errors, but throws an exception at runtime even though code is correct and fine.

Here is my code:

```
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Mail;

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (from.Text != "" && password.Text != "" && to.Text != "" && subject.Text != "" && receive.Text != "")
    {
        try
        {
            MailMessage mail = new MailMessage(from.Text, to.Text, subject.Text, receive.Text);

            SmtpClient SmtpServer = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com");
            SmtpServer.Port = 465;
            SmtpServer.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(from.Text, password.Text);
            SmtpServer.EnableSsl = true;

            SmtpServer.Send(mail);

            MessageBox.Show("Mail Sent");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
            textBox6.Text = ex.ToString();
        }
    }
    else
    { 
        MessageBox.Show("Fill all fields, then press Send button"); 
    }
```

Here is the exception I get:

> System.Net.Mail.SmtpException: The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated. The server response was: 5.5.1 Authentication Required. Learn more at
>
> at System.Net.Mail.MailCommand.CheckResponse(SmtpStatusCode statusCode, String response)
>   at System.Net.Mail.MailCommand.Send(SmtpConnection conn, Byte[] command, MailAddress from, Boolean allowUnicode)
>   at System.Net.Mail.SmtpTransport.SendMail(MailAddress sender, MailAddressCollection recipients, String deliveryNotify, Boolean allowUnicode, SmtpFailedRecipientException& exception)
>   at System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.Send(MailMessage message)
>   at Gmail_Sender.Form1.button1_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Users\junaid

Comment: Does the Gmail account require two-factor authentication? If so, you'll need to create an app password instead.

Answer (score 1):

GMail does not support port 465 for SMTP submission.

You need to use port 587.

That said, they probably won't talk to you anyway, since they're very fussy about IP addresses. If you're on a dynamic range, it's probably not going to work even if you do it correctly.

> IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: net_io_connectionclosed.

The error message indicates that Google didn't want to talk to you and closed the connection.

Comment: still same problem with that port 587

Comment: yes sCheckResponse(SmtpStatusCode statusCode, String response)
   at System.Net.Mail.MailCommand.Send(SmtpConnection conn, Byte[] command, MailAddress from, Boolean allowUnicode)
   at System.Net.Mail.SmtpTransport.SendMail(MailAddress sender, MailAddressCollection recipients, String deliveryNotify, Boolean allowUnicode, SmtpFailedRecipientException& exception)
   at System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.Send(MailMessage message)
  '

Comment: > SmtpFailedRecipientException

That's completely different than the closed connect error you had before. Also, you didn't paste the error, you pasted the stack trace.

Comment: u can compile and run for your satisfaction, believe me an not hiding error message ;d

Comment: What does ex.message and ex.innerexception.message say?

Comment: SmtpFailedRecipientException means that you were able to sucessfully talk to google's server, but the recipient you attempted to send to did not accept your message. If you can step through this with the debugger and view the actual response returned from gmail, you should be able to figure out why they refused the message. You should see a string like 5.n.nn followed by text that indicates the actual problem. "SmtpFailedRecipientException" is just Microsoft's error that means the message couldn't be delivered to the recipient.